# gnu-emacs drag and drop does not work on window

Tags: emacs, drag-and-drop

I have problem with drag-n-drop from outside to gnu emacs.
To investigate the cause,

I wrote and executed these code:

```
(defun dnd-handler (event &optional new-frame)
       (interactive "e")
       (message "Got dnd signal"))


(global-set-key [drag-n-drop] 'dnd-handler)
```

No message appeared, when I dragged a file from desktop to emacs.

Emacs [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Misc-Events.html) states:

> (drag-n-drop position files)
>
> This kind of event is generated when a
> group of files is selected in an application outside of Emacs, and
> then dragged and dropped onto an Emacs frame. The element position is
> a list describing the position of the event, in the same format as
> used in a mouse-click event (see Click Events), and files is the list
> of file names that were dragged and dropped. The usual way to handle
> this event is by visiting these files.
>
> This kind of event is generated, at present, **only on some kinds of systems.**

Does it mean my system is not supported?
My system consists of

GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)
of 2013-03-18 on MARVIN

Window 7 Enterprise 64Bit.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks.

Comment: That combination of OS and Emacs works perfectly for me. Have you tested with an empty ".emacs"?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you're not running Emacs with elevated security, as this can block drag and drop operations from other processes not on the same level.

If you're launching Emacs from a shortcut (.lnk file), right click on it, Properties, Advanced, turn off Run as Administrator.

The same thing can happen if you launch Emacs from a console with elevated security.